# How to add a title and labels for the axis in matplotlib(python)?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have tried to make it like this, but it says **no object attribute to tittle**

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Svg')
from pylab import *
clf()
tittle("frequency of words")
xlabel("words")
ylabel("frequency")
```

Comment: typo error : it is title(...) not tittle(..)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a figure before you can set its title:

```
figure()
title('frequency of words')
```

Comment: So do I need to put clf() as well?

Comment: @Erika Hmm, I'm not sure now. `clf` clears the current figure, but if I run it before creating a figure, it creates one. So your code actually works for me (apart from the typo). But you can try putting `figure()` instead of `clf()` just in case